# Optimize css variables in vulcanized HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, polymer

I'm writing a large web Project using Polymer 1. Sadly we have to support IE 11. We noticed how css variables have a noticeable impact on performance in IE 11. So we decided to replace var() statements with the actual values as far as possible.

We tried using `gulp-html-postcss` together with `postcss-css-variables`. But `postcss-css-variables` honors scoping and does not know about polymer components being able to access css variables from a custom-style. 
As a result, css variables from our custom style are replaced with `undefined` in our components.

The option `preserve:true` (or `preserve:'computed'`) for `postcss-css-variables` did not have the desired effect as no replacement was done at all if any of the two options was set.

Now we are thinking about a quiet blunt approach: We thought about using a regex to find all var() statements and replace them manually.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a tool for replacing css-variables which does not honor scoping?
2. If not, is there a gulp-tool for arbitrarily replacing a regex with a search result from the same file? (Replacing `/var\((\-(?:\-\w+)+)\)/` with the first group from `/$1:\s*(\S+);/` where `$1` is the first group from the *first* regex.)

---

We have

```
<dom-module id="foo-component" assetpath="foos/">
  <template strip-whitespace="">
    <style>
      #stuff{
        background: var(--stuff-background);
      }
    </style>

    <div id="stuff" >
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'foo-component',

      /*ommitted*/


    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
<style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex">

  --background-color: green;
  --stuff-background: var(--background-color);

  .fill-background{
    fill: var(--stuff-background);
  }

</style>
```

Desired result

```
<dom-module id="foo-component" assetpath="foos/">
  <template strip-whitespace="">
    <style>
      #stuff{
        background: green;
      }
    </style>

    <div id="stuff" >
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'foo-component',

      /*ommitted*/


    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
<style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex">


  .fill-background{
    fill: green;
  }

</style>
```

---

Edit: Our postcss-task was

```
gulp.task('reducecss', ['vulcanize'] , function() {
    var path = 'foo/bar/baz/foo.vulcanized.html';
    return gulp.src(path, {base: "./"})
        .pipe(postcss([cssvariables(), calc]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});
```